# Elasticsearch filter query & Nested mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-nested

help me to write the correct filter query Here I used nested mapping and I trying   to filter metric_id =1 is not working correctly
#this is my mapping

```
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
        "properties": {
            "metrics": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## json data

```
{
  'process_date': '2022-03-23T08:16:48.626Z',
  'metrics': [
    {
      'date': '2022-02-23',
      'metric_id': 1,
      'metric_name': 'Total unique_user',
      'timeframe_type': 'D',
      'users_count': 2
    },
    {
      'date': '2022-02-25',
      'metric_id': 1,
      'metric_name': 'Total unique_user',
      'timeframe_type': 'D',
      'users_count': 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-02-01",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "M",
      "users_count": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-02-21",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "W",
      "users_count": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-01",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "Y",
      "users_count": 2
    }{
      'date': '2022-02-23',
      'metric_id': 2,
      'metric_name': 'Total unique_course',
      'timeframe_type': 'D',
      'course_count': 1
    },
    {
      'date': '2022-02-24',
      'metric_id': 2,
      'metric_name': 'Total unique_course',
      'timeframe_type': 'D',
      'course_count': 0
    }
    
  ]
}
```

I'm tried filter queries  metric_id =1 but got all the metric_id documents

GET metrics_test/_search

```
{
  "query": {"nested": {
    "path": "metrics",
    "query": {"bool": {"filter": {"term": {
      "metrics.metric_id": 1
    }}}}
  }}
}
```

GET metrics_test/_search

```
{
  "query": {"nested": {
    "path": "metrics",
    "query": {"bool": {"must": [
      {"match": {
        "metrics.metric_id": 1
      }}
    ]}
  }}
}}
```

## timeframe_type filter  this is working fine

GET metrics_test/_search

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "metrics",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
         "filter": {"term": {
           "metrics.timeframe_type.keyword":"Y"
         }}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output :
1st filter : metric_id =1

```
{
  'process_date': '2022-03-23T08:16:48.626Z',
  'metrics': [
    {
      'date': '2022-02-23',
      'metric_id': 1,
      'metric_name': 'Total unique_user',
      'timeframe_type': 'D',
      'users_count': 2
    },
    {
      'date': '2022-02-25',
      'metric_id': 1,
      'metric_name': 'Total unique_user',
      'timeframe_type': 'D',
      'users_count': 1
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-02-01",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "M",
      "users_count": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-02-21",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "W",
      "users_count": 2
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-01",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "Y",
      "users_count": 2
    }]}
```

2nd filter : metric_id =1 and timeframe_type='Y'

```
{'process_date': '2022-03-23T08:16:48.626Z',
  'metrics': [{
      "date": "2022-01-01",
      "metric_id": 1,
      "metric_name": "Total unique_user",
      "timeframe_type": "Y",
      "users_count": 2
    }]}
```

3rd filter :  metric_id =1 and timeframe_type='Y' and date range 2022-02-23 to 2022-02-30

Comment: do you want to filter `metrics` array based on metric id right ?

Comment: not only metric id  I need to filter timeframe_type, date @SagarPatel